# Is it necessary declaring Enum member as final to achieve immutability?

Tags: java, enums, builder-pattern

I'm using a `Builder Pattern` class in my code, which generate, by the book, the object as `immutable`.
My little doubt is with the enum `Size` member:

```
    public class Pizza {

    private final Size size;
    private final boolean isExtraCheese;
    private final boolean isPeperonni;
    private final boolean isBacon;

    public enum Size {
        SMALL, MEDIUM, BIG
    }
}
```

If enums are consider constants, why can I add the `final` keyword? is it necessary here?

Comment: What would prevent you from doing size = BIG after the pizza has been constructed with a SMALL size if it was not final?

Comment: @JBNizet - here I was confuse about - I wasn't sure I truly need it, since I know enums are constants.

Comment: Well, true and false and 42 and 67 are constants too. final is uses to prevent you from assigning another value to your field. The fact that they are constants (whatever that might mean) is irrelevant.

Comment: Enum constants are final by definition. But variables *referencing* a particular constant may be reassigned, unless they're declared `final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members of the `enum` are constants, but the reference variable referring to enum values is just like any other reference variable, hence the need to mark them as `final`.

You are allowed to do this:

```
private Size size = Size.BIG;
size = Size.SMALL;
```

but marking `size` as final will prevent the second assignment.

```
private final Size size = Size.BIG;
size = Size.SMALL; // this will not be allowed
```

Remember that you are marking a reference variable of the type `Size` as final, not the `enum` `Size` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you had getters and setters and `size` wouldn't be `final`, you could do something like:

```
final Pizza pizza = new Pizza.Builder(Size.BIG, false, false, false).build();
pizza.setSize(Size.SMALL);
```

which would make objects of `Pizza` per definition *not* immutable.